# Adding products and services to the cart from different apps

Tags: django

Hi Everyone,
I am new to python and django and creating a fitness website. I have three apps, one is for the products, one for exercise plans and one for nutrition plans. I am able to add the products in the shopping cart. But wonder how can i do this for the exercise plan app and nutrition plan app. Can any one please suggest a simple way out please. The logic that i have at the moment i can add products from the merchandise app but can any one tell please how i can restructure the logic so that i would be able to add products from exercise

```
here is add to cart:
def add_cart(request, item_id):
    """ Add quantity of specified product to the shopping cart """
    
    quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
    redirect_url = request.POST.get('redirect_url')
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    
    if item_id in list(cart.keys()):
        cart[item_id] += quantity
    else:
        cart[item_id] = quantity
        
    request.session['cart'] = cart
    return redirect(redirect_url)
```

Here is my contexts.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from merchandise.models import Product


def cart_contents(request):
    cart_items = []
    total = 0
    product_count = 0
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})

    for item_id, quantity in cart.items():
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=item_id)
        total += quantity * product.price
        product_count += quantity
        cart_items.append({
            'item_id': item_id,
            'quantity': quantity,
            'product': product,
        })

    context = {
        'cart_items': cart_items,
        'total': total,
        'product_count': product_count
    }

    return context
```

Comment: Your question is way to broad. Could you share what you've already tried or come up with?  Why it should be any different between products and exercise plans/nutrition? These are products as well. Just copy the logic?

Comment: Hi Jonas, thank for your answer. I have added some code so you can take a look. Actually it is required to have multiple apps that's why i have one app for products, one for exercise plans and one for nutrition plans.